# Creating a cascade drop down without primary and foriegn key relationship with coeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

***This is the structure of my table "task"***

1. projectname
2. employee
3. clientname
4. task

**Dependencies are as follows**

1. One project has multiple task
2. One project has multiple employees

I need to create a dropdown list when user selects a particular project tasks relevant to them will automatically load to the next dropdown list. In this situation I do not need primary and foriegn key relationship. Any help would be really appreciated
This is my controller

```
 public function Task(){
    $data['cname'] = $this->welcome4->show_students3();
    $data['projects'] = $this->welcome4->show_students(); 
    $data['employee'] = $this->welcome4->show_students2(); 
    $this->load->view('template/navigation');
    $this->load->view('template/sideNav');
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('Task',$data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');

    }
```

This is my model

```
function show_students2(){
        $query = $this->db->get('employee');
        $query_result = $query->result();
        return $query_result;
    }
    function show_students3(){
        $query = $this->db->get('clientdetails');
        $query_result = $query->result();
        return $query_result;
    }
    function show_students4(){
        $query = $this->db->get('task');
        $query_result = $query->result();
        return $query_result;
    }
```

This is my view

```
<div class="form-group">
                             <label>Select Project</label>
                        </div>     


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="projectname" class="input form-control">
                        <option value="none" selected="selected">Select Project</option>


                        <?php foreach($projects as $s):?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $s->projectname?>"><?php echo $s->projectname?></option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>  
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                             <label>Select Client</label>



                        <select name="cname" class="input form-control">
                        <option value="none" selected="selected">Select client</option>


                        <?php foreach($cname as $s):?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $s->cname?>"><?php echo $s->cname?></option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>  
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                             <label>Select Employee</label>
                        </div> 

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="employee" class="input form-control">
                        <option value="none" selected="selected">Select Employee</option>


                        <?php foreach($employee as $s):?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $s->employee?>"><?php echo $s->employee?></option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>  
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

This loads all projects, clients, employee in the database.But now I want when project is selected in the first drodown, second dropdown should show only relevant clients and employees to it. Not all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets consider this will be your Projects select box, in which you are loading data dynamically on page load with php.

```
<select name="projectname" id="projectname"></select>
```

Tasks select box.

```
<select name="tasks" id="tasks"></select>
```

> Inside your controller add below mentioned code. This function will be used for get data from ajax call.

```
public function getTasks() {
    $Id = $this->input->post('project_id');
    if ($Id):
        $this->load->model('Task_model', 'Tasks', TRUE);
        $data = $this->Tasks->getProjectTasks($Id);
        if ($data):
            $result['status'] = true;
            $result['records'] = $data;
        endif;
    else:
        $result['status'] = false;
    endif;
    echo json_encode($fdata);
}
```

> Inside model please add this function. Which will fetch data from DB
>   ans pass it to controller back.

```
public function getProjectTasks($id = null) {
    if ($id):
        $this->db->select('id,task');
        $this->db->where('project_id', $id);
        $this->db->where('status', TRUE);
        $query = $this->db->get('tasks');
        $records = $query->result();
        if ($records):
            return $records;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;
    else:
        return false;
    endif;
}
```

> And finally in you View file please add below function.

```
$(document).on('#projectname', 'change', function() {
    var projectId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'URL',
        data: {project_id: projectId},
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#tasks')
                    .empty()
                    .append('<option selected="selected">Select Task</option>');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status) {
                $.each(data.records, function(i, item) {
                    $('#tasks').append($('<option>', {
                        value: item.value,
                        text: item.text
                    }
                    ));
                });
            } else {
                $('#tasks')
                        .empty()
                        .append('<option selected="selected">No Task available</option>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Mr.Shyam doesn't this code need a controller and a model?

Comment: Of Course you need this, If you want me to describe you controllers and models than please share your both the tables.

Comment: According to your code let me gives you one example, For rest of this you can able to write code. Please check my updated answer

Comment: Wait I will check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147428/discussion-between-dushee-and-shyam-shingadiya).